# How Long Does It Take to Get a Response After Last Round Technical Interviews for Summer Internships?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I finished a final round technical interview with the CEO of a startup last Friday. How long would it take for them to get back on the results for an internship? The interview said they'd get back around this early this week, but it's already Wednesday so I'm getting worried. I know it's common to get ghosted before getting an interview, but since I've already done two rounds of interview, do y'all think they will at least update me on the status?

Comment: One to infinite days.

Comment: Technical interviews for an internship at a startup, are all red flags to me. Internships at startups just sound like a con to get cheap labor.  What technical knowledge does a person need to have to become an intern? If he can pass a technical interview he should be an employee. If he cannot pass one he should be trained to become one, but what kind of startup is going to take training of newbs seriously? They just all seem to want to pay as little as possible to get the proof of concept done.

Answer (score 2):

The actual questions you're asking are too opinion-based and/or too company specific to answer. We have no idea how long this company would take. We have no idea if they will have the courtesy to update you.

Now, if you had asked "They said they'd get back to me early this week but I haven't heard from them yet, what should I do?" **then** I would have said: probably nothing. It's an internship for a startup, as someone who's been on the hiring side for that situation it is very common for the intended response date to slip by a few days. I wouldn't be concerned yet. That being said, it can never hurt to reach out to them first. There are plenty of questions about this exact topic on this site with good answers, I would look for those to get a better idea of what you might say.